# How to pass a parameter of class?

Tags: android

The Code A works well. I pass a parameter of class in the Code B, but Code B cause an error "It is not applicable for the arguments `(Context, boolean, Class<ReceiverCall>)"` when I try to invoke the function using  EnableOrDisableCallMonitor(myContext, true, ReceiverSMS.class) , why?

And more, using `EnableOrDisableCallMonitor(myContext, true,  Class<ReceiverSMS.class>)` will cause error also.

BTW, The Code C can work, but I don't know if the Code C is good way.

```
  //----------------------------Code A-----------------------------------------
  public void EnableOrDisableCallMonitor(Context myContext, boolean isEnable) {
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(myContext, ReceiverSMS.class);
    PackageManager pm = myContext.getPackageManager();

    int state = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    if (isEnable) {
        state = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
    }
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, state,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}



  //----------------------------Code B-----------------------------------------
  public void EnableOrDisableCallMonitor(Context myContext, boolean isEnable, Class<BroadcastReceiver> myClass) {
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(myContext, myClass);
    PackageManager pm = myContext.getPackageManager();

    int state = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    if (isEnable) {
        state = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
    }
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, state,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}


 //----------------------------Code C-----------------------------------------

     public static void EnableOrDisableCallMonitor(Context myContext, boolean isEnable) {
       PublicParFun.EnableOrDisableBroadcastReceiver(myContext, isEnable,ReceiverCall.class);
     }         

     public static void EnableOrDisableBroadcastReceiver(Context myContext, boolean isEnable, Class myClass) {
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(myContext, myClass);
        PackageManager pm = myContext.getPackageManager();

        int state = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
        if (isEnable) {
            state = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
        }
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, state,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Comment: your question is quite unclear.

Comment: I guest maybe you need a super class, then class a and b inherited it

Comment: The super class of ReceiverSMS is BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generics wildcard in the param type. Change `Class<BroadcastReceiver> myClass` to `Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver> myClass`.

Answer (score 0):

change the signature of the second method (the one in code B) as follows:

```
 public <T extends BroadcastReceiver> void EnableOrDisableCallMonitor(Context myContext, boolean isEnable, Class<T> myClass) {
```

Comment: Thanks! The Code C can work, but I don't know if the Code C is good way.

Comment: Accept one answer (not necessarily min, choose the one that helped you the most) and eventually open another question publishing the code you have chosen as new starting point